# How to implement followers/following using ManyToManyField in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, manytomanyfield, twitter-follow

I want to implement the following feature using manytomanyfield in my Django Application. 
I have created UserProfile class for every user with two attributes: user and follows. User inherit the default Django user model.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name = 'user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name = 'follower',symmetrical=False )
```

I tried this in python shell:

```
>>> lily = User(username="Lily")
>>> lily.save()
>>> mary = User(username="Mary")
>>> mary.save()
>>> lily_profile = UserProfile(user=lily)
>>> lily_profile.save()
>>> mary_profile = UserProfile(user=mary)
>>> mary_profile.save()
>>> lily_profile.follows.add(mary_profile)
```

But I got this error after I do `lily_profile.follows.add(mary_profile)` :

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table polls_userprofile_follows has no column named from_userprofile_id
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Greetings, I wouldn't expect "self" to work for `follows`, but "UserProfile".

Comment: UserProfile is a class. you cannot use the class name inside a class

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your migration file(s) and then rerun below command

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Always Happy coding :)

Comment: If this answer is helpful to you then please upvote and accept it so if anyone else facing the same issue and visit this question, thew will find the trustful answer from here. Thanks :)